# Extract string value of Id from mgo GridFile

Tags: go, mgo

Being quite new to Go, I am having a hard time using mgo.
I am using mgo to fetch files like this :

```
gridfs := db.GridFS("fs")
allFiles := gridfs.Find(nil).Iter()
```

And then I use the returned iterator like

```
        var f *mgo.GridFile
        for gridfs.OpenNext(allFiles, &f) {

            //use f.Id()
        }
```

I want to start using f.Id() as a String but I am unable to convert. One of the ways I found was by using `fileId := (f.Id().(bson.ObjectId)).Hex()` which just lets me compile but fails at runtime with the message `interface conversion: interface {} is bson.ObjectId, not bson.ObjectId`

Having spent a lot of time on this already, I am definitely open to changing the way I fetch the files if conversion is not possible using `GridFile`.
I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: It may be you have multiple versions of `mgo` in your project. Can you can check and post your imports? And check your Go workspace if you have multiple version of `mgo`?

Comment: @icza that was it. Feel so annoyed having spent so much time. Thanks a lot for your help. I ll mark this as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer by @icza. I had 2 versions of mgo.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer then in order to prevent this question from showing up in the "unanswered" list.